# No connection string named '' could be found in the application config file

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class library with a method that takes a string and returns an xml document.  This library references another project - containing edmx models generated with EF6 db first.

I realize that my connection strings from the EF project must be moved into the "executing" application config file - this is fine in development as I have created a simple web client as my startup project and it's web.config contains the necessary connection strings.

When I deploy this solution to my QA server, the "executing" application is actually a VB6 app and I am getting this error.  I have no idea what application config file is being used in this case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think your issue looks way too localized for anyone to help you.